# Redirect using htaccess (IP based or Language based)

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a client with a multi language website. the client want that when someone open the site it should be direct redirect based on his location to the proper language.
I know it is not a good way but as they say ( the client is always right ) and i cant change that.
the Website have 5 Languages ( 3 to be honest )

- German (Deutsch) as default
- English (UK)
- English (USA)
- France
- English (international)

i added the following in htaccess:

```
# Redircet GeoIP
RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} ^(FR)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://forprivacyicantwritethesitename.com/fr/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} ^(GB)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://forprivacyicantwritethesitename.com/en-uk/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} ^(US)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://forprivacyicantwritethesitename.com/en-us/$1 [L,R=301]
```

but its not working, the site will not work.
as alternative i used this Code

```
# language is EN USA
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^en-us [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /en-us/home [L,R=301]

# language starts with DE
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^de [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /startseite [L,R=301]

# language starts with FR
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^fr [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /fr/page-d-accueil [L,R=301]

# language is EN UK
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^en-gb [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /en-uk/homepage [L,R=301]
```

but i got a feedback that's it not working all the time.

Any Ideas guys?

Comment: Did you install, configure & activate the geoip Apache module to begin with ...?

Comment: You could try and dump available enviroment variables in a script; or you could simply do a `RewriteRule ^foo$ bar?%{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} [R=302]` - and then request `/foo`, and see if that redirects you to `/bar` with an actual country code value appended, or not.

Comment: Regarding the second one, _"but i got a feedback that's it not working all the time."_ - not all clients might send an `Accept-Language` header, it might have gotten filtered out for privacy reasons for example.

Comment: And despite _"the client is always right"_, you need to make it clear to them, that if they want to redirect automatically, they at least need to provide the user with a way to deliberately select a different language version of the site (i.e., overwrite the automatic choice.) I will probably not be in control of what Accept-Language header the browser in that French internet cafe I am currently sitting in, will send, "my" IP will say "is in France" as well in that scenario - but that doesn't mean that I speak or can read French.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working" exactly? The first rule block will likely result in a redirect loop if mod_geoip is installed/enabled but will do nothing at all if it's not. "but i got a feedback that's it not working all the time" - Your second rule block is quite different to the first in that it **only redirects the homepage** (to specific URLs - which the first rule block does not do)? So, yes, it won't work all the time since it doesn't work for all URLs.

Comment: @CBroe thanx alot for the Infos, i will try that.
i already tried my best with the Client but sometimes it simply does not work.

Comment: @MrWhite the First Code (reDirect over IP) didt work at all thats why i used the 2nd one. as an alternative.
the Problem im not totally sure if the Admin of the Server (thats not me, i only do the Typo3 programming) did everything write, and he says that he did everything